# Em qual realidade Kony Framework é a melhor escolha?

Tags: javascript, mobile, arquitetura-de-software

Hoje o mercado está buscando cada vez mais frameworks para um desenvolvimento hibrido de aplicativos mobile. Um framework que já havia ouvido falar era o Kony, pois foi escolhido pelo Itau (Recentemente Trocado).

Gostaria de entender um pouco mais sobre este framework:

- Em qual realidade de projeto o Kony é a melhor escolha?
- Quais as vantagens do Kony como Framework?
- Qual o motivo dos frameworks híbridos trabalharem, em sua maioria, com javascript e derivados?

Conferi no site do framework e eles possuem outros grandes players em seus clientes (Localiza, FarmaTodo, etc.)

Comment: Olá Luiz, eu sugiro você dividir sua dúvida em mais perguntas. Existem três asssuntos na sua *bullet list*... O primeiro pode ser facilmente considerado como principalmente baseado em opiniões. Os outros dois são boas perguntas e cada um merece uma resposta diferente.

Comment: Não conhecia, e fiquei impressionado, seria Kony um app inventor que presta? kk

Comment: Acredito que não, pelas minhas pesquisas ele é bem ruim de utilizar e dar manutenção, por isso queria entender o que leva alguem a escolhe-lo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Em qual realidade de projeto o Kony é a melhor escolha?**

Quando você tem serviços legados que tem saída em SOAP, pois ele possui uma ferramenta integrada chamada Mobile Fabric que permite a fácil conversão para JSON para você realizar suas chamadas RESTful.

**Quais as vantagens do Kony como Framework?**

Ele possui uma rápida curva de aprendizado pois utiliza javascript para sua implementação, possui uma equipe por trás para oferecer suporte e gera código nativo.

**Qual o motivo dos frameworks híbridos trabalharem, em sua maioria, com javascript e derivados?**

Creio que pela simplicidade e familiaridade, por ser uma linguagem que é comum em várias linguagens, por exemplo, programadores que tem familiaridade com asp.net, php, entre outras linguagens web geralmente tem javascript como linguagem em comum, além disso javascript é ponto de interseção entre os dois sistemas operacionais mais utilizados para celular.

Comment: Pelo que vi o kony tão péssimo feedbak, você acha que ele é uma escolha acertada?